# How do I call for a hidden value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

As of right now I have a JS which searches a page and when a specific value is found it will cause an alert. For exmaple, if the id of "finished" appears in the html then it would cause an alert.

```
function notEmpty(){
var myTextField = document.getElementById('finished');
if(finished.value != "")
    alert("You entered: " + finished.value)
else
    alert("It worked!")     
}
```

Is it possible to do with a hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submittedStep" value="finished" style="display:inline;">
```

I've tried almost everything I can think of and can't find a solution

Comment: hidden elements have no special meaning in JS, they work the same way as all others. So whatever you did - the issue is not the hidden type.

Comment: @joe That works perfectly and is a great alternative but what I'm really looking to do is use the JS to find the the value="finished"

Answer (score 1):

Add an id attribute to your hidden input:

```
<input id="finished" type="hidden" name="submittedStep" value="finished" style="display:inline;">
```

Comment: YOu don't really need IDs to select elements - you can do so by walking through the entire DOM tree, by using getElementsByTagName, getElementsByName or possbily another 1000 ways. BUt as I'm not really sure what the OP is asking, your answer may still fit.

Comment: @JohannesH. Of course not. But the specific reason the code he posted isn't working is because the element he's looking for doesn't have an ID matching what's in his code.

Comment: I understood the question a little different, because `IF the id of "finished" appears` sounds like "but it is not the case" to me. BUt again: there is way to tillte information in the question to tell wether I'm right or not. I just wanted to add some alternatives to your answer, in case that I'm right an the OP knows there is no ID, but cannot modify the HTML.

Comment: Thanks @mansfield that does work perfectly. I think I was just over complicating things and that is a great alternative. Is there a way of using the JS to cause an alert if there is a hidden value of finished?

Comment: @banduchanan You can check to see if the element exists by comparing the result of `getElementById` to null, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: well @mansfield I guess what I'm trying to say, and I suppose it might be what you just said but I'm not 100% sure what that means. I'm searching right now simply by id="finished" which is fine but ideally I'de like to be searching for value="finished". How would that look?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that directly...it would be better to add a hidden element with a specific id. You could do it with jquery though.

Answer (score -1):

You're using this:

```
var myTextField = document.getElementById('finished');
```

But the object doesn't have an id of 'finished':

```
<input type="hidden" name="submittedStep" value="finished" style="display:inline;">
```

Comment: Sorry - I hate downvoting, but I did in this case because it doesn't answer the question. It answers why his existing code doesn't work, but the actual question is "how do I do this", not "why is my code broken".

Comment: Are you kidding?  How about an answer to 'how do I do this' is 'use this code that isn't broken?'

Comment: Well, pedantically, that would be a non-constructive answer. But seriously, [@Mansfield's post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19939875/1454048) directly answers the original question.